# Shared object all over the project in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

My question was probably already asked before, but I don't know if my keywords are good.

In Qt, I'm looking for a way to have a object that will be common to all other objects:

[image: A drawing is always better]

I don't want to use signals/slots, because in a case of imbricated objects, I would need to make the signal go through the parents and I'm pretty sure this is not a good solution.
I also want this common object to be the same object all over the project. I can't declare a new MyCommonClass on every object that will use it.

This is something I have never done in cpp and I really don't know how to deal with it.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you consider singleton pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern?

Comment: I would assume that the `MainWindow` instance is one with the longest life-time lasting nearly over the complete run-time of application. Hence, it might be a good container for the single instance of `MyCommonClass`. (Just in case, you don't like the idea of a global instance which a singleton usually uses.)

Comment: @sheff but how the other objects can access easily MyCommonClass without signals/slots ?

Comment: You dont need to implement signals/slots in your singleton. There is no need to inherit from QObject at all. Just execute regular function calls.If you describe  in more detailwhat you want to achieve, we can give some recommendations.